# Filter elements with both integer and NA in R

Tags: r, filter, integer, na

I am relatively new to R, and I have a simple question.
I have df as below.

```
df <- data.frame(T = c('A','A','B','B','C','D'), P = c(10, NA, 22, NA,33,NA))
```

After some filtering process, I want to see only the elements that have both an integer and NA from column P: in this case, only A and B remain.

What would be the best way to get this?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a condition in `filter` to have both `NA` and non-NA after grouping - `is.na` returns TRUE for NA, `!` converts the `TRUE` -> `FALSE` and viceversa.  `sum` of the logical vector get the count, then change it to a logical vector (`> 0`  - count of NA greater than 0, count of non-NA greater than 0)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(T) %>% 
   filter(sum(is.na(P)) > 0, sum(!is.na(P)) > 0) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  T         P
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A        10
2 A        NA
3 B        22
4 B        NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!